# Can we check multiple variables against same expression in python

Tags: python

I know we can check a variable against multiple conditions as

```
if all(x >= 2 for x in (A, B, C, D)):
    print A, B, C, D
```

My question is , can we do the reverse? 
can we check one or two variables against same conditions(one or two)

```
null_check = (None,'','None')
if variable1 not in null_check and variable2 not in null_check:
    print (variable1, variable2)
```

can we rewrite the above code as

```
if variable1 and variable2 not in null_check:
    print (variable1, variable2)
```

If yes, which one is a better practice ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the variables in a `list` or `tuple`, then use the same idea using `all` to check that none of them are in your `tuple`.

```
if all(var not in null_check for var in (variable1, variable2)):
    print (variable1, variable2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very similarly to your first code block:

```
null_check = (None,'','None')
if all(variable not in null_check for variable in (variable1, variable2)):
    print (variable1, variable2)
```

Or:

```
null_check = (None,'','None')
variables = variable1, variable2 # defined elsewhere
if all(variable not in null_check for variable in variables:
    print (*variables)
```

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do that, but as a pythonic approach you can put your `null_check` items in a `set`. And check the intersection:

```
null_check = {None,'','None'}
if null_check.intersection({var1, var2}): # instead of `or` or `any()` function
    # pass  
if len(null_check.intersection({var1, var2})) == 2: # instead of `and` or `all()` function
    # pass
```